# Can I sell Premium Hakururi sake from 1953?

Tags: sake

I found this in my parents basement. I can’t imagine the premium sake is any good but the bottle is beautiful.

Comment: Can you sell it? Of course. Are you asking if it is drinkable? Or whether you can make some money?

Answer (score 1):

**Can I sell Premium Hakururi sake from 1953?**

You can most certainly try to sell it. But the real question is the sake still drinkable?

If you try to sell it, the buyer should know exactly what he is buying and any circumstances that surrounding the bottle of sake.

I personally fell that the bottle may be a great souvenir, but the contents may not be good!